# Applescript + REST?

Tags: rest, applescript

Does AppleScript have a way of interacting with REST APIs?

I realize I can

```
do shell script curl
```

Comment: I think using `curl` is the way to go.

Comment: Are you talking this? http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/soapXMLRPC/chapter1/soapXMLRPC_intro.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fetch and parse an XML file using AppleScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280362/how-to-fetch-and-parse-an-xml-file-using-applescript)

Answer (score 7):

I would use curl in

```
do shell script "#curl script here"
```

If you need  help to get the correct curl statement I recommend [postman](http://getpostman.com), It helps me really to generate the right code. But remember If you have these: `"` to put an escape character in front: `\"`.

So for example if i want to do a POST request to

```
https://api.widerstandsberechner.ch/api.php?firstcolor=red&secondcolor=orange&thirdcolor=yellow&fourthcolor=silver&hasFiveRings=0&resultInText=0
```

the AppleScript would look like this:

```
do shell script "curl -X POST -H \"Cache-Control: no-cache\" \"https://api.widerstandsberechner.ch/api.php?firstcolor=red&secondcolor=orange&thirdcolor=yellow&fourthcolor=silver&hasFiveRings=0&resultInText=0\""
```

And of course you can easy assign the result as a value:

```
set res to do shell script "curl -X POST -H \"Cache-Control: no-cache\" \"https://api.widerstandsberechner.ch/api.php?firstcolor=red&secondcolor=orange&thirdcolor=yellow&fourthcolor=silver&hasFiveRings=0&resultInText=0\""
```

Hope this helps!